# SQL query: Replace blank space before SECOND quote?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a SQL table with about 16k rows. 
The table contains a varchar column where I need to do some mass edits.

I have about 3000 rows that I need to edit and I'll give you an example on how they look:

```
Lionel Messi plays football for "Barcelona " since a few years back.
```

I want the blank space before the second quote gone and end up in this result:

```
Lionel Messi plays football for "Barcelona" since a few years back.
```

If I do a SELECT, I get the rows that I want with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE text LIKE '%"% "%';
```

But when I'm trying to make this one in to a replace, I can't get it to work. I've been trying this one:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET text = REPLACE(text, '%"% "%', '%"%"%') 
WHERE text LIKE '%"% "%';
```

Anyone have any idea on how to proceed from here? My gut feelings tells me that I need to exclude the blank space from the wildcard but I have no idea on how to do that.

I'm in MySQL 5.5.31

Comment: Always a good idea to specify which platform you are using since the string functions on SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and MySQL are all slightly different.

Comment: Are all your replacements prior to the last `"` in the string?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that information. I'm working in MySQL.
All replacements are prior to the last (and second) ".

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem, it replaces all occurrences of `[space]"[space]` with `"[space]`. It's worth noting that if you have `[space]"[space]` somewhere else in that field it will also replace it.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET text = REPLACE(text, ' " ', '" ') 
WHERE text LIKE '%"% "%';
```